# Static allocation of struct members within another static struct?

Tags: c, struct, static-members

I am trying to implement a low-level thread lock without the use of dynamic memory allocation; this code will basically be used on a completely bare-bones kernel.

However, I am running into the problem of receiving a seg fault when I am trying to dereference a member inside this global static struct. My code is as such

My wrapper struct

```
/** LOCKING STRUCT & FUNCTIONS **/
struct lock {
    int free;
    struct thread_list* wait_list;
    struct thread* current_holder;
};
```

The nested struct(intended as a linked list sort of deal)

```
struct thread_list {
    struct thread *head;

};
```

And the member inside this list

```
struct thread {
    void *top; // top of the stack for this thread
    void *sp;  // current stack pointer for this thread (context)
    void (*start_func)(void *);
    void *arg;
    int state;
    int exit_value;
    struct thread *join_thread;
    struct thread *next_thread;
    int id;
};
```

The method I'm trying to implement is as such

```
void lock_init (struct lock *lk) {
    lk->free = 1; //Set lock as free
    struct thread_list waiting = lk->wait_list; //Get waitlist, works fine
    waiting->head = NULL; //Set waitlist's head to null, SEGFAULTS HERE
}
```

I am not super proficient at C, but I can't seem to figure out the correct methodology/syntax to make my code work like this.

Comment: this line: `struct thread_list waiting = lk->wait_list;`  does NOT work fine.  it is setting the contents of a non pointer struct to a pointer.  Perhaps the line should be: `struct thread_list *waitingPtr = lk->wait_list;` or similar

Answer (score 1):

```
struct thread_list waiting = lk->wait_list; //Get waitlist, works fine
waiting->head = NULL; //Set waitlist's head to null, SEGFAULTS HERE
```

`waiting` is not a struct pointer but a struct variable . To access member using it you need to use `.` operator -

```
 waiting.head = NULL;
```

Or to use `->` operator declare it as a struct pointer .

Comment: I switched it to a struct pointer, which allowed for compilation but still segfaulted. Then I tried using "." to reference head but it led to an "invalid initializer" error.

Comment: figured it out! the problem was that I was declaring it as a pointer in my top-level struct but that was causing the compiler not to set aside space for it. removed the * from the original and that worked fine.

Comment: @WilliamChiang If you were to use pointer then before derefernceing it allocate memory to it , to avoid error .